# Jest assertion that response.redirect was called

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, jestjs

I'm using jest to test a route controller. The controller method is something like

```
async function MyController(req, res, next){
     if (condition1) {
        // render logic
     }
     if (condition2) {
        res.redirect(SOME_CONSTANT);
     }
}
```

How do I assert that the response.redirect has been called? I've tried

```
const req = { query: {} };
const res = { redirect: jest.fn() };
expect(res.redirect).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

But that's obviously not going to work unless I can actually mock `reponse` with `jest.mock()`. Can I mock the base http response model?

Answer (score 3):

Just check the amount of times that it was called:

```
const myController = require('../my-controller')

describe('my-controller', () => {
  let res

  beforeEach(() => {
    res = {
      redirect: jest.fn(),
    }
  })

  test('should call res.redirect', async () => {
    await myController({}, res)
    expect(res.redirect.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myController = require('../my-controller');

describe('my-controller', () => {
  let res;

  beforeEach(() => {
    res = {
      redirect: jest.fn(),
    };
  });

  test('should call res.redirect with the correct arguments', async () => {
    // Arrange
    const expectedRedirectUrl = '/some/path';

    // Act
    await myController({}, res, expectedRedirectUrl);

    // Assert
    expect(res.redirect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(res.redirect).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedRedirectUrl);
  });
});
```

**This should worked better and have better coverage**